# docker-compose file dosn't update correctly

Tags: docker, deployment

i have an issue with docker toolbox on windows 10, i followed the official tutorial of docker https://docs.docker.com/get-started/part5/#add-a-new-service-and-redeploy ,i used a docker-compose.yml and when i delete a service from that file (visualizer service that i added it using the above tutorial) and deploy it again to a swarm manager, the deleted service is still running.

commands used : 
- docker stack deploy --with-registry-auth -c docker-compose.yml getstartedlab

- docker stack ps getstartedlab

Are there any solutions to update correctly the docker-compose.yml ?
or to delete a service ?

[results of docker stack ps](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u1lmi.png)

Comment: How are you deleting the service? Include your commands please and please review [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: i am deleting the service by deleting the statements in the docker-compose.yml and redeploying

Comment: i am deleting the service by deleting the statements in the docker-compose.yml and redeploying, initially i followed the tutorial but i didn't have the same results as the tutorial (the vizualizer service display no container in my second vm myvm2) so i tried to delete the vizualizer service within the docker-compose.yml but it dosn't want to be deleted and it still persists to running